# Upload progress bar in jQuery

Tags: jquery, upload, progress-bar

I'm trying to do a very very simple upload images script with a simple upload bar, i read some tutorials and this is what i try:

I have a progress bar

```
<div id="progressbar">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS style

```
.bar {
    height: 18px;
    background: green;
 }
```

And my jQuery script

```
$.ajax({
                xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        console.log(percentComplete);
                        $('#progressbar .bar').css('width',percentComplete + '%');
                        if (percentComplete === 100) {
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
                },
                url:'upload.php', 
                type:'POST', 
                contentType:false, 
                data:data, 
                processData:false, 
                cache:false, 
                success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
                }
            }).done(function(msg){
                $("#cargados").hide().html(msg).fadeIn("fast"); 
            });
```

The part thats sends the files to upload.php is working perfectly and showing the info in #cargados, but the part of the progressbar is doing nothing. What i'm doing wrong?

Thank you a lot
ecazorla

Comment: Might be a problem with your HTML. Does your #progressbar .bar have a height?

Comment: Are you using jQuery File Upload plugin?

Comment: change your math to `(data.loaded/data.total)*100`

Comment: use option `async`, set it to `false`

Comment: is `progresall`correct method for `ajax` ?

Comment: Im not using jQuery File Upload plugin

Comment: I asked because your code really looks like the one shown here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#how-to-display-upload-progress-with-the-basic-plugin

Comment: And if I'm remember well theres no such option as progressall for jQuery's AJAX

Comment: I taked the code from a forum, now im thinking that "progressall" is a function of that plugin, right? thats the reason why it doesn't works

Comment: Correct @EstebanCazorla!

Answer (score 0):

The `progressall` option is from jQuery Upload Plugin hence you should put your progressall function callback in this part of the code:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    /* ... */
    progressall: function (e, data) {
    var barra = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    $('#progressbar .bar').css(
            'width',
            barra + '%'
    );
}
```